# How to call a function that uses default parameters in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function

Let's say I have a function like:

```
function get_param ($param1, $param2 = 'value2', $start = 0, $end = 0){
   //do stuff with params
}
```

And I call it different times within an html page that has two ajax POST-call to a php script.

The first ajax call pass just the first parameter (param1) and the second one pass all parameters (param1, param2, start, end). I'm trying to call the `get_param()` function passing the first parameter (param1) always and the others just if they are inside the call ( inside the `$_POST` array). Otherwise the function has to use his default.

This is my try but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
if($_POST){
include_once '../includes/functions.php';

if(isset($_POST['param2'])) $param2 = $_POST['param2'];
else $param2 = null;

if(isset($_POST['start'])) $start = $_POST['start'];
else $start = null;

if(isset($_POST['end'])) $end = $_POST['end'];
else $end = null;

$result = get_param($_POST['param1'], $param2, $start, $end);
echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: passing null is still passing null, you have to either not pass the arguments at all, or figure out another way to do this, using an array comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguemnts only used when you don't pass an argument in its place.

```
$result = get_param($_POST['param1']);
```

The function would have these values: get_param($_POST['param1'], 'value2', 0, 0)

If you want to do it with null s, like in your code, then you need to check the value of the argument. Like this:

```
function get_param ($param1, $param2, $start, $end){
   $param2 = ($param2 == null) ? 'value2' : $param2;
   $start = ($start == null) ? 0 : $start;
   $end = ($end== null) ? 0 : $end;
}
```

Comment: This isn't elegant solution (as default paramters should be entered in the function declaration, not body). For example for programmers enviroments auto hints. But in that case this is the only possible solution I think. +1.

Comment: I agree this is not elegant but surely does the job, thanks! if some one have a different solution any advice will be appreciated.